# Character encoding issue when importing into WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, drupal, character-encoding

I've created a routine to migrate content from Drupal to WordPress. Basically I'm querying the Drupal database within a PHP script, then using `wp_insert_post()` to add that data into the WordPress database.

I'm having an issue with character encoding, where by after I've inserted the Drupal content into WordPress certain characters cause the remainder of the string to be stripped.

Take this example:

```
<strong>The following text will stop at the back tick’, this text will get stripped out</strong><br />
```

When importing this, anything after the back tick is remove, as such:

```
<strong>The following text will stop at the back tick
```

To try to remedy this issue I've attempted to change the character encoding, however this strips out the back tick, funky space-like character, as well as characters like the pound `£` symbol.

```
$html = iconv('utf-8', 'us-ascii', $html);
```

I've also tried `//TRANSLIT` and `//IGNORE` with this function, but still it either completely removes these characters or stops at the first problem.

Can anyone advise on a way to get the content into format of which will be accepted by WordPress, but without removing these characters, but convert them to an alternative.

**Edit**

I've also tried passing the string through `htmlentities()`, however this returns an empty string.

Additionally I've attempted to determine the encoding of the string using `mb_detect_encoding()`, but this returns false, meaning it cannot detect the encoding.

**Edit 2**

When I view the Drupal database record in hex mode the back tick returns as `‚Äô`.

Comment: There's no help if we don't know what the routine does.

Comment: I've added some more info to the question, but as originally stated, it migrated content from Drupal to WordPress.

Comment: I know that wordpress tries to convert quotes and many other characters to UTF-8 equivalents, and I would guess it's inside this `wp_insert_post()` function. Try going that direction. I hope you are not going to blog about coding, I really hate copypasting from wordpress sites for this very reason.

Comment: If I leave the `wp_insert_post()` method to it's own devices issue occurs, I'm trying to fix it before I pass the content to this method.

Comment: There's many magic going on inside `wp_insert_post()`. Look at how `sanitize_post_field()` works. Your content might be fine, it's just wordpress messing things up.

Comment: Try to call `kses_remove_filters()` before the migration, `kses_init_filters()` after migration.